# duplicate handling, sorting with dict

Tags: python

i have this little part of code that is causing me problem because i am trying to remove the duplicate from the result i get and sort it from the words. Well i have tried many code from the forum but most of them do the sort from a list so i'm a little bit confused there. I wonder what needed to be added. I have tried sorting options, pprint, also set() and nothing seems to work. Tell me if u need my full code for more understanding. i hav also tried to convert to tuples to sort and back to dict but it didnt work.

exemple of input

```
i.py d1.txt apples orange bananas plants apples
```

Example of actual output:

```
apples: 30
oranges : 13
bananas : 20
plants : 0
apples: 30
```

example of needed output

```
apples: 30
bananas : 20
oranges : 13
plants : 0
```

Here is a little part of my code where the modification needs to be done.

```
    entree = essaie[1]
    for items in essaie[2:]:
        choix = str(entree)
        texte = choix.strip("[']")
        resultat = ligne(texte, items) #this is my dictionary
        if items in resultat.keys():
            print(items, ": {}".format(resultat[items]))
        else:
            print(items, ": 0")
```

Comment: Presumably you just need a `set` of the input values, e.g. `for items in set(essaie[2:]):`, but order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: oh thanks it fixed my duplicated i wasnt putting the set on the right variable, still need to fix that sorting.

Comment: oh ok i found it i just had to add sorted(set(essaie[2:])): thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

found the answer it was sorted(set(essaie[2:]))